# Convergence of the integral of product of $L^p$ and $L^q$ functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be finite Holder conjugates, and let $f_n$ be a sequence of $p$-integrable functions converging pointwise to $f$. Suppose there is some uniform constant $C$ such that $\|f_n\|_p < C$ for all $n$. Prove that if $g \in L^q$, then
$$ \int f_ng \to \int fg. $$
The "obvious" estimate where one uses Holder's inequalty does not work here since we do not have $f \in L^p$ or that $\|f_n - f\||_p \to 0$. I can't find a dominating function, so I do not know how to use the convergence a.e. criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f_n \in L^p(X)$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. then apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence $|f_n|^p$, which converges pointwise to $|f|^p$, then we see 
\begin{align}
\int_X |f|^p\ d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X |f_n|^p \leq C^p. 
\end{align}
Hence $f \in L^p(X)$. To show $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^p$, it suffices to show for all characteristic function $\chi_E$ where $\mu(E)<\infty$  we have
\begin{align}
\int_X f_n\chi_{E}\ d\mu =\int_E f_n\ d\mu\rightarrow \int_E f\ d\mu. 
\end{align}

Now, let us take out the big guns.  Since $\|f_n\|_p \leq M$, then $f_n$ are uniformly integrable.  Hence by [Vitali Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem), we indeed have
\begin{align}
\int_E f_n\ d\mu \rightarrow \int_E f\ d\mu. 
\end{align}

Edit: To prove uniform integrability, observe for every $A \subset E$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_A f_n\ d\mu \leq \| f_n\|_p \mu(A)^{1/q} \leq C\mu(A)^{1/q}.
\end{align}

Comment: Why does the uniform bound imply uniform integrability?

Comment: Use Holder's inequality.

Comment: Ah right I forgot you reduced it to the case where the space is finite.

Comment: I can do that because $p , q \neq \infty$.

Comment: We are using $\sigma$-finiteness here, yes?

Comment: No. We used the fact that simple functions are dense in $L^p$ for $1\leq p <\infty$.